# EL Exception on JSP when passing arguments to liferay-ui:message

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, jstl, el

So Im trying to use this line on my JSP:

```
<liferay-ui:message key='test.mymessage' arguments='${number}'/>

test.mymessage = Number is {0}
```

And i am getting this error:

```
javax.el.ELException: No puedo convertir 10 desde tipo class java.lang.Integer a class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

which roughly translates to:

```
javax.el.ELException: Can't convert 10 from type class java.lang.Integer to class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

I even tried:

```
<liferay-ui:message key='test.mymessage' arguments='10'/>
```

Odd thing is, this has worked forever and started failing just a few days ago, and some of my work mates can run this jsp without a problem. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

As described in [Arguments in liferay-ui:message](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6796965)

> The tag accepts an attribute named 'arguments' of type Object [].

Therefore the following snippet should work:

**Passing argument through scriptlet:** (If you are passing single argument)

```
<liferay-ui:message key="test.mymessage" arguments="<%=number %>" />
```

OR

**Passing argument through EL:**

```
<%
    Integer[] arguments = new Integer[]{number};
%>
<liferay-ui:message key='test.mymessage' arguments='${arguments}' />
```

Comment: That is the theory, but the fact is that up to a few days ago, it used to work with a single element, also if I use a scriptlet (`<%=number%>`) oddly enough it works

Comment: Well, I have never tried. This is what based on above reference.